# unable to run docker container (image size 9 GB) from AWS instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-ec2, amazon-ecs

Inspite of creating EC2 instance (of type t2.xlarge) we are unable to run the application.

FYI:
Created the task/container as per the documentation

Created  the cluster/service

The error message is **Essential container in task exited**

any help ??

Thanks

Comment: That error message is not enough to point the issue, you might be need to dig more for logs and more information.

Comment: The more important question is: why is your Docker image so insanely large?

Comment: we are using openface deeplearning technologies for close match  of the human face. moreever we are training 2 GB dataset (human faces) to create the binary file. Is there any size limitation for creating docker images ?

Answer (score 0):

I would imagine a couple issues could potentially point you in the right place. Without further information it's a little hard to diagnose.

1.) Your docker image is too large and the instance volume is not big enough to hold it. SSH into your server and run `df -h` to verify that the size of the host volume can store the image.

2.) Usually when your containers exit unexpectedly or they continue to launch and die it is a resource allocation issue. For a test I would only run 1 task for that service and give it 100% of the resources of the host machine cpu/mem. And in this case with a t2.xlarge I believe it would be `4096 cpu` and `16384 mem`. Your service could very well be turning on, using too much memory, and restarting.

3.) Is the image even downloading? Do the security groups allow outbound access to download it? Where are you storing your images? Is there a size limitation?

4.) Login to the ECS server and check the logs to watch the service bounce. It should show a more detailed error there.

Comment: 5) If ECS is not giving extra info, it might be some configuration in the host itself. Connect to the host that receives the docker image. Do a 'docker ps -a' in the docker host to identify the container, and then 'docker log herecontainerId'. This should give you some hint about why the container exited.

Comment: You didn't provide enough resources in task defination or health checks problem